# Do not print if $previous_line matches $current_line.*

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I would like to be able to use `awk` in place of a while loop to remove subdomains from an input string if it also contains the main domain.

Source file:

```
1234.f.dsfsd.test.com
abc.test.com
ad.sdk.kaffnet.com
amazon.co.uk
analytics.test.dailymail.co.uk
bbc.co.uk
bbc.test.com
dailymail.co.uk
kaffnet.com
sdk.kaffnet.com
sub.test.bbc.co.uk
t.dailymail.co.uk
test.amazon.co.uk
test.bbc.co.uk
test.com
test.dailymail.co.uk
```

Desired Output:

```
amazon.co.uk
bbc.co.uk
dailymail.co.uk
kaffnet.com
test.com
```

Solution: [@EdMorton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51821524/6763661)

Comment: What's the idea with reversing the string? What are you doing there? State the input and expected output clearly

Comment: The desired output and input from file are at the top. The idea behind reversing and then sorting is that it groups all of the same domains together, starting with the TLD (test.com). It's then possible to check each line after the previous to see if it is a subdomain of the TLD

Comment: The previous line check may be irrelevant but I wasn't aware of a better way to do it :)

Comment: @mmotti: How would we know where the line `test.com` would occur? Could it in anyline in the file? If so how to identify it?

Comment: @Inian The file is a list of domains that has been reversed and sorted. The TLDs should appear immediately before the subdomains.

Comment: How do you expect a script in Awk to know which countries have second-level domains per default? This is undoable unless you use some libraries in Python or Perl. Have a read to [Top-level domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain) in Wikipedia and see how this can get very complicated.

Comment: @fedorqui Understood, but my issue here is not to determine whether or not a single domain is a TLD or a subdomain, it's to read each line of the reversed, sorted input string and determine whether the current_line matches previous_line.* - The idea here is to count every domain as a wildcard, so if I have `test.com` in my list, I do not need the next line `1.test.com`. Reversing the string, sorting it and regex matching the previous line is as far as I need to go in terms of determining if it's a TLD.

Comment: Yes, your issue is that because you expect `bbc.co.uk` in the output, while currently we just can give you `co.uk`.

Comment: @fedorqui even if we deviate from using `.` as the FS?

Comment: @mmotti well we can use the second last field, but then `bla1.test.com` and `bla2.test.com` will count as different domains in your final result. It really depends on how you can to approach this. If you just have `.uk` domains that have this problem, you can try to hardcode a solution for those; however, if the input is quite random and can have various domains from different countries, you'd better check some proper libraries that check domains.

Comment: @fedorqui I have updated the description with desired processing - Does this make more sense? All I need it to do is loop through each line and process in that way. The domains are really varied, but I don't think determining the prefix is the issue - It's being able to regex match the current reversed line against the previous reversed lines, and only printing if we are on the first line or there is no match.

Comment: @mmotti yes, I understand the problem and it is these kind of things that look very obvious on first glance but then become complicated when digging a big :D We can do as you say and it will work because "bbc.co.uk" occurs first in the text, before any other "bbc.co.uk". Is this always the case? Is this why you reverse and sort? Does it mean that the full domain is always present  or can it be that we just have lines like "bla.bbc.co.uk" "ble.bbc.co.uk"? If the main domain is always present, then we may be close to the solution with the reverse+sort approach :)

Comment: @fedorqui It is always the case and that is the reason for the reverse and sort - It puts everything in the perfect order for the iteration that we need. The main domain is not always present, so if `bbc.co.uk` was not in the list, `bla.bbc.co.uk` would be acceptable to print. I only want to remove subdomains if the main domain (i.e. `bbc.co.uk`) is in the list :-)

Comment: In the future, please avoid changing the input so many times you keep making the answers obsolete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New answer based on new requirements and new sample input file:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ doms[$0] }
END {
    for (domA in doms) {
        hasSubDom = 0
        for (domB in doms) {
            if ( index(domA,domB ".") == 1 ) {
                hasSubDom = 1
            }
        }
        if ( !hasSubDom ) {
            print domA
        }
    }
}

$ rev file | awk -f tst.awk | rev
bbc.co.uk
dailymail.co.uk
amazon.co.uk
kaffnet.com
test.com
```

---

```
$ rev file | sort |
  awk -F'.' 'index($0,prev FS)!=1{ print; prev=$1 FS $2 }' |
  rev
bbc.co.uk
test.com
```

The above just implements the algorithm you described in your question. It reverses the chars on each line and then sorts the result just like you were already doing, then if the previous line was `foo.bar.stuff` then `prev` is `foo.bar` and so if the current line is `foo.bar.otherstuff` then the call to index WILL find that `foo.bar.` (note the `.` at the end - adding that last `.` to the comparison is important so that `foo.bar` doesn't falsely match `foo.barristers.wig`) DOES occur at the start (index position 1) of the current line and so we will NOT print that line and `prev` will remain as is. If, on the other hand the current line is `my.sharona.song` then `prev` (`foo.bar`) DOES NOT occur at the start of that line and so that line IS printed and `prev` gets set to `my.sharona`. Finally it just reverses the chars on each output line back to their original order.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177979/discussion-between-mmotti-and-ed-morton).

Answer (score 3):

Check the last part of a domain and see which string is the shortest one among them:

```
BEGIN{FS="."}
{
    ind=$(NF-1) FS $NF;
    if (!(ind in size)  || (size[ind] > length)) {
       size[ind]=length  # check the minimum size for this domain
       domain[ind]=$0    # store the string with the minimum size on this domain
    }
}

END {for (ind in domain) print domain[ind]}
```

As a one-liner:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS="."} {ind=$(NF-1) FS $NF; if (!(ind in size)  || (size[ind] > length)) { size[ind]=length; domain[ind]=$0}} END {for (ind in domain) print domain[ind]}' file
test.com
bbc.co.uk
```

---

#### Previous approach, that works for top level domains:

Just make use of the field separator and set it to the dot. This way, it is just a matter of storing the penultimate and last one as a string and check how many different ones you find:

```
$ awk -F. '{a[$(NF-1) FS $NF]} END{for (i in a) print i}' file
test.com
```

How does this work? `a[]` is an array to which we keep adding indeces. The index is defined with the penultimate field followed by a dot and the last field. This way, any new `bla.test.com` will still have the same index and do not add extra info into the array.

With other inputs:

```
$ cat file
1234.f.dsfsd.test.com
abc.test.com
bbc.test.com
test.com
bla.com
another.bla.com
$ awk -F. '{a[$(NF-1) FS $NF]} END{for (i in a) print i}' file
test.com
bla.com
```

Comment: What kind of dark magic does `a[$(NF-1) FS $NF]` do?

Comment: Thanks - Does this accommodate for domains that have more than one suffix, though? Such as bbc.co.uk or test.bbc.co.uk?

Comment: @mmotti nope, this is for just one level domains, as seen in your given input. In general, checking these kind of things with some parsing must be done just for very basic cases. For the rest, it is best to use proper tools to check proper domains.

Comment: @vdavid I edited to explain a bit more. Let me know if it is not clear!

Comment: @fedorqui It's clearer, thank you. But then it stops at the penultimate dot. For instance if the file is `msdn.blog.microsoft.com
blog.microsoft.com` then you will get `microsoft.com`. @mmotti would you expect `microsoft.com` or `blog.microsoft.com` in this case ?

Comment: @vdavid exactly, I just made it work for first level domains.

Comment: @vdavid I only want to return the TLD. I will update the description as I didn't make this clear. It needs to be able to strip the tld from domains that could have more than one suffix (.co.uk), as an example. Sorry that I didn't make this clearer.

Comment: @mmotti note that a [Top level domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains) is a well defined concept and `.co.uk` is not one of those. On the contrary, `.co` in it is a second-level domain.

Comment: @fedorqui Sorry - I am getting my terminology mixed up. I just want the domain without the subdomain :-)

Comment: @fedorqui is this input for this answer meant to be reversed / sorted? [Testing here](https://awk.js.org/?gist=c99f52b6b53ad4a0089841abd1630baf)

Comment: @mmotti nope, I do not perform any reverse to the text, so you input should be the original file.

Answer (score 1):

You can test a dynamic regex inside awk if you build a variable with the `~` operator

```
awk 'NR==1{a=$0} NR>1{if(length(a)>0){regex="^"a;if($0~regex){print a}}a=$0}'
```

[Example](https://repl.it/repls/FlatLoyalDecompiler) (using tac and rev to facilitate the reversion)

The problem with your method is that you need at least 2 lines for the domain because you only display the previous line, but *what if* you did not have a previous line? Maybe that is not an issue for you if your domains always come with at least 2 lines.

Comment: Could this be resolved if the regex match was able to be placed in the if statement? So we say, if there is no value for A || regex not match then print? What is the significance of the NR==1?

Comment: @mmotti If you talk about the issue that needs 2+ lines, I'm afraid not because you explicitly said you wanted to compare lines two by two. But if you are ready to get rid of that condition, the other suggested answers may be better.

Comment: Sorry - There may be some confusion as I am not sure about the best way to go about this.

The while loop checks for either: No previous line || Current line not-match previousline.*

I wasn't sure if I could emulate this behaviour in `awk`.

Comment: A regexp comparison is the wrong approach since `ab.de` will regexp match `abcde`, and so on. You should be doing a string comparison.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, here is a version that works without requiring reversing and sorting the input.

```
awk -F. 'BEGIN {
    SLDs = "co.uk,gov.uk,add.others" # general-use second-level domains we recognize
    split(SLDs, slds, /,/);
    for (i in slds) slds[slds[i]] = 1
}
/./ {
    tld = $(NF-1) "." $(NF)
    if (NF > 2 && tld in slds) tld = $(NF-2) "." tld
    lines[NR] = $0
    tlds[NR] = tld
    if (tld == $0) existing_tlds[tld] = 1
}
END {
    for (i = 1; i <= length(lines); i++) {
        line = lines[i]; tld = tlds[i]
        if (!(tld in existing_tlds) || tld == line) print(line)
    }
}' input_file
```

This goes through the file and builds an array of existing TLDs. In the `END` block it prints a line only when it is a TLD itself *or* its TLD does not exist in said array.

When `input_file` is

```
1234.f.dsfsd.test.com
abc.test.com
amazon.co.uk
bbc.co.uk
bbc.test.com
sub.test.bbc.co.uk
test.amazon.co.uk
test.bbc.co.uk
test.com
```

it prints

```
amazon.co.uk
bbc.co.uk
test.com
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative approach. Does this also handle things like bbc.co.uk, test.bbc.co.uk without issue?

Comment: @mmotti No, I didn't think of that. Currently it considers the two last parts of the domain name the TLD. I have to make an extra case for those, but I need to read up on them first.

Comment: It doesn't produce the posted expected output from the posted sample input. FYI [@fedorqui's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51819789/1745001) already concisely does what you're trying to do with this script.

Comment: @EdMorton Except that @fedorqui's answer doesn't really work. If you add `sub.test.foo.co.uk` to the input, then according to what the OP wants (*"remove subdomains from an input string if it contains the top level domain."*, i.e. keep the subdomain if it doesn't), this line should be output.

Comment: Sounds like the OP needs to provide more comprehensive sample input and expected output if what she's provided so far doesn't cover all the cases she needs to handle.

Comment: @mmotti Now it has a facility for defining which "second-level TLDs" you want to support. The rules for this differ quite a bit per country, it is very difficult to generalize. Therefore I've settled on a white-list.